# Windows partition not showing during installation of Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

When I was installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 10, only one disk was showing up. However, I created a swap area and a partition for Ubuntu and installed it. When I restarted the computer, the boot options did not come up, and the system booted directly into Ubuntu.

Some websites are not opening in Ubuntu.  Firefox says "Failed to connect." The Wi-Fi is not working.

How can I access my files from Ubuntu or boot into Windows.

Comment: Can you edit your question and clarify what you mean by "access my files from Ubuntu"?  For example, do you mean: How can I access the files on my Windows' partition from Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes I mean access the files on my windows partition from Ubuntu

Comment: You're asking a question, produce a statement and ask another question. They are not related. 1) Why doesn't Windows show up at boot? 2) I'm having trouble with browsing the internet under Ubuntu/Firefox. 3) How can I see my Windows files from Ubuntu? Please ask 1 question at a time, preferably after having read the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 5):

Boot options might not appear if GRUB is convinced there is only one bootable drive. You can force the GRUB menu by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> immediately after turning on your PC.

You can run this command to re-generate your GRUB boot menu and it will attempt to find any other operating systems:

```
sudo update-grub
```

You can run this commands to see your disks:

```
gnome-disks
```

This will give you options to *mount* your existing Windows disk or determine why it's not being detected. Sometimes if Windows was not shutdown properly it sets a flag saying it needs to be "checked" or "repaired" in which case Linux will not touch it. You can have Linux do the repair if you do this:

```
sudo apt install ntfs-3g
sudo ntfsfix /some/disk
```

In this case `/some/disk` is a disk path like `/dev/sdXXX` - this varies between system and you should take caution to not "fix" the wrong disk. If the package `ntfs-3g` doesn't exist try installing `ntfsprogs` instead.

Comment: `/dev/XdY` where `X` is `s` for SCSI, `h` for MFM/RLL and `Y` is `a`...`z`

Comment: @Fabby Thanks, although I doubt anyone in 2018 is running a "real" SCSI drive :D

Comment: SAS is still "real" SCSI...  **;-)**

Comment: I'm willing to bet this user has a SATA drive or NVME like most modern laptops. Either way it's a subjective debate of which hardware users are running the most or what a "Ubuntu user" is.